# Validating Jenkins plugin forms with Ruby

Tags: ruby, validation, jruby, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm developing a Jenkins plugin in Ruby. You're supposed to be able to configure every node that connects to the server so that an email is sent to a specified address when the node loses its connection to the master. `EmailNodeProperty` adds a field to enter an email address:

```
# 
# Save an email property for every node
#
class EmailNodeProperty < Jenkins::Slaves::NodeProperty
    require 'java'
    import 'hudson.util.FormValidation'  

    display_name "Email notification"

    attr_accessor :email

    def initialize(attrs = {})
        @email = attrs['email']
    end

    def doCheckEmail value
        puts "  ENP.doCheckEmail:#{value}"
    end
end
```

When you configure a node, there's a field named `email` where you can enter an email address. I want this field to be validated when you enter an address.

When you save the configuration, an `EmailNodeProperty` is created whence (that's right) you can access the email address.

`MyComputerListener`'s `offline` gets called when a node loses its connection:

```
class MyComputerListener
    include Jenkins::Slaves::ComputerListener
    include Jenkins::Plugin::Proxy

    def online(computer, listener)
    end

    def offline(computer)
        #Do nothing when the Master shuts down
        if computer.to_s.match('Master') == nil
            list = computer.native.getNode().getNodeProperties()
            proxy = list.find {"EmailNodeProperty"}
            if proxy.is_a?(Jenkins::Plugin::Proxy)
                rubyObject = proxy.getTarget()
                email = rubyObject.email #<= Accesses the email from EmailNodeProperty
                [...]
            end
        end
    end
end
```

`MyComputerListener` finds the email address and sends an email.

Does anybody know if it is possible to validate the form in Ruby? According to the [Jenkins wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Basic+guide+to+Jelly+usage+in+Jenkins), this is what's supposed to be implemented (FIELD is supposed to be exchanged for the field name, so I guess it should be `doCheckEmail`):

```
public FormValidation doCheckFIELD(@QueryParameter String value) {
    if(looksOk(value))
        return FormValidation.ok();
    else
        return FormValidation.error("There's a problem here");
}
```

How would you do this in Ruby? Where should the method be implemented? In `EmailNodeProperty` or in `MyComputerListener`? How do you handle the QueryParameter? The @ would make it an intstance variable in Ruby. (What is a Queryparameter?)

Any help would be much appreciated!

/Jonatan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simply doesn't exist today, and we badly need to add it. This has been brought up a couple of times already in [Thursday morning's hack session](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+plugin+development+in+Ruby), so it's high on the TODO list. But as of [ruby-runtime plugin 0.10](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins.rb/tree/master/java-runtime), this just isn't possible. Sorry to let you down.