# onOffline / offline called twice when server goes down

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm developing a plugin for Jenkins. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9410490/1135951)'s a link to another question with all my code (but it's kind of irrelevant).

I've implemented a `ComputerListener` whose `onOffline` method gets called when a computer disconnects. But when the server goes down `onOffline` gets called twice for every connected computer. The plugin is written in Ruby but the problem remains in Java. Why is that and can it be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in Jenkins <= 1.451 and is now resolved in 1.452. In the latter version, onOffline is only called once per computer. It is also only called on the connected computers. Not on the non-connected computers, as in the former version.